# Looping through DOM elements including span elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to get a function to work but haven't had any luck so thought I would ask a newbie question to the Stackoverflow brains-trust!

Basically, I have a form and I'm looping through all the elements to see if there is a custom data attribute present.  If it's there, keep the element visible but if it's not there, hide the element.

When I use the function below, it's looping through all the input fields on the form but it ignores any span or div elements, even if they have the 'data-group' attribute with a value of 'FocusGroup'

```
function DropDownSelection_Focus(FocusGroup)
{
var elements = frm_FormName.elements;
var el;
for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) 
    {
    el = elements[i];
    var GetGroup = document.getElementById(el.name).getAttribute('data-group');
    if (GetGroup != null && GetGroup !='')
        {
        if (GetGroup == FocusGroup.value)
            {
             document.getElementById(el.name).style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        else
            {
            document.getElementById(el.name).style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The span/div elements have both an id and name values so is there a reason why they are being excluded from the loop?

Comment: do you know jquery?

Comment: no, not yet but it's on my 'to-do' list once I've learnt the basics of JS

Comment: This may help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('#form :not([data-group])')` Should select all elements in your form (with id `form`) that doesn't have data-group attribute.

Comment: here is a fiddle for you thats hides a div on special condition https://jsfiddle.net/cqtkocga/

Comment: Thanks guys ... I'll give it a try later tonight, along with Georgi's suggestion below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element property of FORM object returns a collection of all elements in a form. Elements mean a input, textarea, button or select. Something that support "user action" - can be pressed, selected or etc. If you want to get all elements that have data-group attribute you can use something like this:

```
var elementsWithGroupAttr = frm_FormName.querySelectorAll("*[data-group]");
```

frm_FormName is form (the variable from your code snippet).

Comment: OK, that makes sense then ... would I be better using querySelectorAll() as that seems to be coming up in some of my searches

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for helping solve this issue.  I was able to get my loop working with the following (for the benefit of others searching at a later date):

```
var elements = frm_FormName.querySelectorAll("*[data-group]");
var el;
for (var i=0, iLen=elements.length; i<iLen; i++) 
{
el = elements[i]
var GetGroup = el.getAttribute('data-group');
    if (GetGroup == FocusGroup.value)
    {
    el.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else
    {
    el.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

Whilst Georgi's was the only 'answer' to be the accepted one, help from Werner, yariash and lordkain is also acknowledged.

Thanks everyone!